# Can PHPMailer add a different greeting for each recipient

Tags: email, phpmailer

I have a working implementation of PHPMailer where I send an email to multiple recipients.

Now I would like to pass a customized greeting into the mail body for each recipient: Hello Joe, Hello Miss Jones, Hi M. Brown...etc

These greetings would be strings associated with each recipient and would either be loaded from the DB or created by a side function.

My current understanding is that this can't be achieved with a single email as each greeting would create a distinct email body, thus making it a standalone email.

I'm looking for a way to mass-customize a message in a way that services like mailchimp offer. 
Is there some way to loop through the recipient list when the mail is created and inject recipient-specific content ?

Or would I need to create an email for each recipient ? (would that be feasible?)

Or is this a case to use another service like mailgun or sendGrid ?

Thanks for any pointers towards a workeable approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would need to send a separate email to each recipient. This is outside PHPMailer's area of responsibility, but that's fine as there are other libraries available to help. A good way to do that is to use a templating system, which can be just PHP itself, but things like Smarty or Twig work fine. Take a look at [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).

Comment: Thanks for making this clear. I'll try and get a working example based on the mailing-list example. From what volume would this approach cause any problems, if any ? 1k / 10k ?

Comment: It's not up to the code, it's up to how good your mail server is and how much email your ISP allows you to send. I have no problem sending 600k/hour using this basic approach.